# change case from odd/even argument

Tags: string, python-3.x, function, uppercase, lowercase

how should I define a function that takes in a string and returns the string in upper and lowercases according to even and odd indexing?

```
def myfunc(string):
    for some in string:
        if string.index%2==0:
```

I have written this much but I do not know what should I type now.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can find the string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) Specially look at upper() and lower() which will be your friend here.